# Completely wipe out the dijit (dojo) tree from memory and free its placeholder

Tags: html, tree, dojo

I begin with piece by piece of code so that the problem description becomes clear.

1. I have a piece of HTML code as:

   `<div id="center" class="column" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer">`

   ```
    <div id="first" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="first"  selected="true">

       <div id="first_content"></div>

   </div>

    <div id="second" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="second">

        <div id="second_content"></div>

    </div>
   ```

   `</div>`
2. I have a javascript function to load the dijit trees into HTML :

function load()

```
{
//load data
dojo.xhrGet(firsthierarchy("first_content", "file1.json"));
dojo.xhrGet(secondhierarchy("second_content", "file2.json"));
}

function firsthierarchy(node, url){
return {
url: url,
node: dojo.byId(node),
handleAs: "json",
load: loadfirsthierarchy
};
}

function secondhierarchy(node, url){
return {
url: url,
node: dojo.byId(node),
handleAs: "json",
load: loadsecondhierarchy
};
}

function loadfirsthierarchy(data, xhr)
{
if(xhr.args.node)
{
store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
treeModel1 = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
store: store1,
query: {
"type": "continent"
},
rootId: "root",
rootLabel: "Continents",
childrenAttrs: ["children"]
});
tree1 = new dijit.Tree({ 
        model: treeModel1, 
    },xhr.args.node.id);
}
}

function loadsecondhierarchy(data, xhr)
{
if(xhr.args.node)
{
store2 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
treeModel2 = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
store: store2,
query: {
"type": "continent"
},
rootId: "root",
rootLabel: "Continents",
childrenAttrs: ["children"]
});

tree2 = new dijit.Tree({ 
model: treeModel2, 
},xhr.args.node.id);
}
}
```

All of the above functions are working fine. Now, I want to have a reset function such that it can wipe out the existing trees in the "first_content" and "second_content" div and load those divs with new trees having new content. Eg:

function reset()

```
{
// here I want to completely wipe out the exiting trees in all of the dojo contentpanes.
// And I want to load the contentpanes with entire new set of data.
// Maybe like :
// dojo.xhrGet(firsthierarchy("first_content", "file3.json"));
// dojo.xhrGet(secondhierarchy("first_content", "file4.json"));
}
```

I have no idea on how to implement the reset function. Could you please provide me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep references to the tree, treeModel and store, then define your function as:

```
reset: function() {
    myTree.destroyRecursive();
    myTreeModel.destroyRecursive(); // I'm not 100% sure you need this, destroying the tree may do this automatically
    delete myStore
}
```

That should do the trick

The way I'd do this is to create a module using dojo.provide called `TreeWrapper()` which handles the Tree lifecycle (fetching the data, creating the tree, killing the tree). This wrapper module then has the reset function above and can contain references to all the different variables.

You'll also need to keep track of any `dojo.subscribe`'s you have for the tree and unsubscribe from those.